# ktor dependencies not resolved in ios module of multiplatform project

Tags: android, ios, ktor, kotlin-multiplatform

I have a kotlin-multiplatform project targeting iOS and Android.
Ktor http client is used in common module.

Everything works great with Android app.
But when building project with iOS lib, I receive following exceptions:

```
> Task :app:compileKotlinIos FAILED
src/commonMain/kotlin/com/ottamotta/mozoli/api/MozoliApiKtor.kt:4:8: error: unresolved reference: io
import io.ktor.client.HttpClient
       ^
src/commonMain/kotlin/com/ottamotta/mozoli/api/MozoliApiKtor.kt:5:8: error: unresolved reference: io
import io.ktor.client.features.feature
```

...and other ones, saying none of the ktor dependencies have been resolved.

Here is build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'kotlin-multiplatform' version '1.3.10'
}
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://kotlin.bintray.com/kotlinx" }
}

ext {
    support_lib_version = '28.0.0'
    ktor_version = '1.0.0'
}

def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file("./app/secret.properties");
def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.ottamotta.mozoli"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        manifestPlaceholders = [auth0Domain: "@string/com_auth0_domain", auth0Scheme: "https"]
    }
    buildTypes {

        debug {
            resValue "string", "com_auth0_client_id", keystoreProperties['com_auth0_client_id']
        }
        release {
            resValue "string", "com_auth0_client_id", keystoreProperties['com_auth0_client_id']
            minifyEnabled false
        }
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }


}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:${support_lib_version}"
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${support_lib_version}"
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'

    implementation "com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin:2.9.7"

    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.0.1")
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.0.1'

    implementation "com.auth0.android:auth0:1.14.1"

    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
}

kotlin {
    targets {
        fromPreset(presets.android, 'android')
        // This preset is for iPhone emulator
        // Switch here to presets.iosArm64 (or iosArm32) to build library for iPhone device
        fromPreset(presets.iosX64, 'ios') {
            compilations.main.outputKinds('FRAMEWORK')
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        commonMain {
            dependencies {
                implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common'
                implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client:$ktor_version"
                implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-json:$ktor_version"
                implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-jackson:$ktor_version"
            }
        }
        commonTest {
            dependencies {
                implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-common'
                implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-annotations-common'
            }
        }
        androidMain {
            dependencies {
                implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib'
                implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-android:$ktor_version"
            }
        }
        androidTest {
            dependencies {
                implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test'
                implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-junit'
            }
        }
        iosMain {
            dependencies {
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-ios:$ktor_version")
            }
        }
        iosTest {
        }
    }
}

task copyFramework {
    def buildType = project.findProperty("kotlin.build.type") ?: "DEBUG"
    def target = project.findProperty("kotlin.target") ?: "ios"
    dependsOn "link${buildType.toLowerCase().capitalize()}Framework${target.capitalize()}"

    doLast {
        def srcFile = kotlin.targets."$target".compilations.main.getBinary("FRAMEWORK", buildType)
        def targetDir = getProperty("configuration.build.dir")
        copy {
            from srcFile.parent
            into targetDir
            include 'app.framework/**'
            include 'app.framework.dSYM'
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the code of the file from common module which generates errors:

```
package com.ottamotta.mozoli.api

import com.ottamotta.mozoli.*
import io.ktor.client.HttpClient
import io.ktor.client.features.feature
import io.ktor.client.features.json.JsonFeature
import io.ktor.client.features.json.JsonSerializer
import io.ktor.client.features.json.defaultSerializer
import io.ktor.client.request.header
import io.ktor.client.request.request
import io.ktor.client.request.url
import io.ktor.http.HttpMethod


class MozoliApiKtor(
    private val serverUrl: String,
    private var jsonSerializer: JsonSerializer? = null,
    private val tokenProvider: suspend () -> String?
) : MozoliApi {

    private val client: HttpClient

    private val AUTH_HEADER = "Authorization";
    private val TOKEN_PREFIX = "Bearer "

    init {
        client = HttpClient {
            install(JsonFeature) {
                serializer = jsonSerializer ?: defaultSerializer()
            }
        }
        jsonSerializer = client.feature(JsonFeature)?.serializer
    }

    override suspend fun getUserProfile(): User {
        return client.request {
            url("${serverUrl}/user/")
            method = HttpMethod.Get
            header(AUTH_HEADER, TOKEN_PREFIX + tokenProvider())
        }
    }

    override suspend infix fun getEventsByCity(cityId: String): List<Event> {
        return client.request {
                url("${serverUrl}/event/city/${cityId}")
                method = HttpMethod.Get
                header(AUTH_HEADER, TOKEN_PREFIX + tokenProvider())
            }

    }

}
```

Comment: It looks like transitive dependency fail to resolve.
Could you try to add

 `implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-core-ios:$ktor_version"` 
explicitly?

Comment: Thanks for reply @Leonid, unfortunately still having same errors, with the following dependencies in build.gradle:  iosMain {
            dependencies {
                implementation ("io.ktor:ktor-client-core-ios:$ktor_version")
                implementation ("io.ktor:ktor-client-ios:$ktor_version")
            }
        }

Comment: btw there are no common Jackson feature

Comment: Could you try that config: https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlinconf-app/blob/master/common/build.gradle ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I was having the same exact issue as you. Built and works flawlessly for the Android app, but the iOS module cannot find any Ktor, coroutine, or kotlinx serialization class.

Following along https://github.com/adrianbukros/github-multiplatform-example, and trying to copy their set up, I finally got the `packForXCode` task to work by copying some of their gradle set up namely:

Their common module `build.gradle`, which should look like this:

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-multiplatform'
apply plugin: 'kotlinx-serialization'

kotlin {
    targets {
        fromPreset(presets.jvm, "android")

        fromPreset(presets.iosX64, "ios_x86_64")
        fromPreset(presets.iosArm64, "ios_arm64")
        configure([ios_x86_64, ios_arm64]) {
            compilations.main.outputKinds("FRAMEWORK")
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        commonMain.dependencies {
            implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib"
            implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core-common:$coroutines_version"
            implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-runtime-common:$serialization_version"

            implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-core:$ktor_version"
            implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-json:$ktor_version"
        }

        androidMain.dependencies {
            implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
            implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:$coroutines_version"

            implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-runtime:$serialization_version"

            implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-core-jvm:$ktor_version"
            implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-json-jvm:$ktor_version"
        }

        iosMain.dependencies {
            implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core-native:$coroutines_version"
            implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-runtime-native:$serialization_version"

            implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-ios:$ktor_version"
            implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-core-ios:$ktor_version"
            implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-json-ios:$ktor_version"
        }
        configure([ios_x86_64Main, ios_arm64Main]) {
            dependsOn iosMain
        }
    }
}

// workaround for https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-27170
configurations {
    compileClasspath
}

task packForXCode(type: Sync) {
    final File frameworkDir = new File(buildDir, "xcode-frameworks")

    final String configuration = project.findProperty("CONFIGURATION")?.toUpperCase() ?: "DEBUG"
    final String arch = project.findProperty("ARCHS") ?: "x86_64"

    dependsOn kotlin.targets."ios_${arch}".compilations.main.linkTaskName("FRAMEWORK", configuration)

    from { kotlin.targets."ios_${arch}".compilations.main.getBinary("FRAMEWORK", configuration).parentFile }
    into frameworkDir
}

tasks.build.dependsOn packForXCode
```

And their `settings.gradle` file which should look like this:

```
enableFeaturePreview("GRADLE_METADATA") // IMPORTANT!

include 'commoncode'
include 'app'
```

If it's still not working, look at all of their `*.gradle` and `gradle.*` files and see how yours are different.

That finally allowed the task to pass for me, and I can use my Kotlin Ktor code in XCode. However, now Android Studio is saying "Kotlin is not configured" for the shared iOS module. I will report back if I figure out why, and if you find something, please share!

**EDIT**
Changed the common module `build.gradle` to look like this, seems like everything is working well!

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-multiplatform'
apply plugin: 'kotlinx-serialization'

kotlin {
    targets {
        fromPreset(presets.jvm, 'android')

        // Change to `presets.iosArm64` to deploy the app to iPhone
        fromPreset(presets.iosX64, 'ios') {
            compilations.main.outputKinds('FRAMEWORK')
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        commonMain.dependencies {
            implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib"
            implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core-common:$coroutines_version"
            implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-runtime-common:$serialization_version"

            implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-core:$ktor_version"
            implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-json:$ktor_version"
        }

        androidMain.dependencies {
            implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
            implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:$coroutines_version"

            implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-runtime:$serialization_version"

            implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-core-jvm:$ktor_version"
            implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-json-jvm:$ktor_version"
        }

        iosMain.dependencies {
            implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core-native:$coroutines_version"
            implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-runtime-native:$serialization_version"

            implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-ios:$ktor_version"
            implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-core-ios:$ktor_version"
            implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-json-ios:$ktor_version"
        }
    }
}

// workaround for https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-27170
configurations {
    compileClasspath
}

task packForXCode(type: Sync) {
    final File frameworkDir = new File(buildDir, "xcode-frameworks")
    final String mode = project.findProperty("XCODE_CONFIGURATION")?.toUpperCase() ?: 'DEBUG'

    inputs.property "mode", mode
    dependsOn kotlin.targets.ios.compilations.main.linkTaskName("FRAMEWORK", mode)

    from { kotlin.targets.ios.compilations.main.getBinary("FRAMEWORK", mode).parentFile }
    into frameworkDir

    doLast {
        new File(frameworkDir, 'gradlew').with {
            text = "#!/bin/bash\nexport 'JAVA_HOME=${System.getProperty("java.home")}'\ncd '${rootProject.rootDir}'\n./gradlew \$@\n"
            setExecutable(true)
        }
    }
}

tasks.build.dependsOn packForXCode
```

Comment: Thank you! `enableFeaturePreview("GRADLE_METADATA")` make it work for me.

Comment: Yeah same here, `enableFeaturePreview("GRADLE_METADATA")` made it work for me too.

Comment: ```enableFeaturePreview("GRADLE_METADATA")``` allowed me to build also

Answer (score 0):

As of now kotlin multiplatform for iOS does not run on windows. This would explain why only the dependencies in your iosmain code wont resolve.